# I need to get a a specific value from Json file using powershell

Tags: json, windows, powershell

I converted a plain text inside note-pad to JSON file using this command ConvertTo-Json;
so how do I get the specific key value that equivalents to note-pad text content?

```
    get-content -Path c:\Users\ayyub\oneDrive\Desktop\Jayson.txt | ConvertTo- 
    Json
```

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your .json looks like this:

```
{
    "person": {
        "kevin": {
            "phone": "00000099999"
        }
    }
}
```

After converting the .txt to a .json you can probably try this:

```
$json = (Get-Content "example.json" -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json

$json.person.kevin.phone
```